# Incorrect duplicate: missing clock

Tags: support, duplicates

The question [My clock has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/q/362653/3986) is incorrectly marked as a duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 gnome issue, no clock is shown, strange starter icon cannot be removed](https://askubuntu.com/q/233769/3986). Could someone who has the necessary reputation please vote to reopen the question, please?

There are several comments on the question and answers pointing out that one is referring to Gnome, and the other is referring to Unity.